# How do you call an overridden MSBuild target

Tags: .net, msbuild

In MSBuild you can override a `<Target />` from another file in your own. For example the *AfterBuild* target included in `Microsoft.Common.targets` file simply by defining your own Target with the same name:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <!-- Do something different -->
</TargetName>
```

You'll see a note like this:

Overriding target "AfterBuild" in project "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets" with target "AfterBuild" from project "XXXXX".

**Is there any way to call the original AfterBuild target?**

I'd like to do this to instrument certain complex default Targets and then execute the  original behavior. Many targets like Build expose a BuildDependsOn property that can be used for this. Many others do not - and I'd like to override them without completely duplicating their content.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When an MSBuild script is processed it will also process the imported files. The result will be a single in memory canonical representation of the entire script. When a target is encountered that already exists the previous definition is discarded, therefore it is not possible to call the original target.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to do this to instrument certain complex default Targets and then execute the original behavior. Many targets like Build expose a BuildDependsOn property that can be used for this. Many others do not - and I'd like to override them without completely duplicating their content.

If you want to first run something custom on a target and then run the original target, why not just use `BeforeTargets`?

So instead of

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <!-- custom AfterBuild overriding default AfterBuild -->
</TargetName>
```

just use

```
<Target Name="JustBefore_AfterBuild" BeforeTargets="AfterBuild">
    <!-- custom AfterBuild just before default AfterBuild -->
</TargetName>
```